# Copy a line of text to a file and numbering it

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I want to make several copies of a line of text, following a numeric order.

```
exampleline:

exampleline1
exampleline2
exampleline3
etc..
```

What's the basic way to get the desired number of copied lines into a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash` you do something like this:

```
bash-4.1$ for i in {1..5}; do
> echo exampleline$i
> done > examplefile.txt
bash-4.1$ cat examplefile.txt
exampleline1
exampleline2
exampleline3
exampleline4
exampleline5
bash-4.1$
```

And here's how you might do it with `tcsh`.  (I had to use the `>>` append operator because `tcsh` doesn't support i/o redirection on a control structure.)

```
tcsh-6.18.01% @ i = 1
tcsh-6.18.01% while ( $i <= 5 )
while? echo exampleline$i >> examplefile.txt
while? @ i++
while? end
tcsh-6.18.01% cat examplefile.txt
exampleline1
exampleline2
exampleline3
exampleline4
exampleline5
tcsh-6.18.01%
```

Comment: @charley If you click to "accept" my answer you'll push me over 5000.  Yippee. :)

Answer (score 2):

In bash using `printf`:

```
printf 'exampleline%s\n' {1..5} > examplefile.txt
```

Comment: This is a very clever use of this (frankly, advanced user) behavior in `bash`.  This particular syntactical feature has always struck me as an intriguing design choice.  I'm not sure why Fox chose to make `bash` behave this way, iterating over the list, rather than either (a) like the C library `printf`, which takes only the first arg and ignores the rest, producing `exampleline1` or (b) coercing the list of numbers 1 through 5 into a string, `1 2 3 4 5`, producing the result `exampleline1 2 3 4 5`.  What's odd about it is that feature only applies to `printf`, not just any command.